# Join Array of Arrays on property

Tags: javascript

I have two objects as follows below. I would like to merge the contents of one of the array to the contents of the another array based on a property. I know that this is achievable by joining in database query but I was hoping to do the merge server side to better familiarize myself with javascript

```
const tasks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
    items: [
        {
            name: 'dishes',
            completed: false
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'jane'
    items: [
        {
            name: 'sweep',
            completed: true
        },
        {
            name: 'vacuum',
            completed: false
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

and

```
const progress = [
    {
        id: 1
        items: [
            {
                name: 'dishes',
                progression: 50
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        items: [
            {
                name: 'sweep',
                progression: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'vacuum',
                progression: 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I go about getting the object to look like below?

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john'
    items: [
        {
            name: 'dishes',
            completed: false
            progression: 50
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'jane'
    items: [
        {
            name: 'sweep',
            completed: true
            progression: 100
        },
        {
            name: 'vacuum',
            completed: false
            progression: 10
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

Cheers!

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge might interest you

Comment: check out `Array.concat()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat if you want to do it in pure JS

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that items will always have 1 item then below function should work for you

```
function merge(){
   const merged = tasks.map(task=>{
     let progres = progress.find(progres=>progres.id===task.id)
     if(progres){
       task.items = [{...task.items[0],...progres.items[0]}]
     }
     return task;
   });
   return merged;
}
```

Comment: I should have made that more clear in the code above. Items may have more than 1 item in the collection

Comment: @AksharPatel How could you make the code clear if it actually does nothing as in no function no effort to show what you attempted to do. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @AksharPatel if your "name" is the correlating property in items then you can refer above array.find function and merge your items. Try and post your code if you are facing issues.